# Prevent empty string in Entity column in TypeOrm

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I want to prevent the insertion of an empty string for a `string` column.

Aside: Yes I can do the constraint in the DB, and I will do that.

I would like it so if an empty string is assigned to that property, typeorm will automatically null it.

For example, I imagine something like:

```
@Entity()
class Foo {
  @Column()
  @NoEmptyString()
  bar: string;
}
```

and then if someone were to:

```
const foo = new Foo();
foo.bar = '';
repository.save(foo);
```

then foo would be inserted with `NULL` as the value of `bar`.

TypeORM also has [validations](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/validation)
but they actually seem to all come from [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) and need to be called manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity()
class Foo {
  @Column()
  @NoEmptyString()
  bar: string;

  @BeforeInsert()
  @BeforeUpdate()
  replaceEmptyStringAsNull() {
    if (this.bar === '') {
      this.bar = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that would probably work. It's a little verbose. I would definitely prefer a concise decorator, but something like this would probably work.